# Symlinking parent directory doesn't show subdirectories being symlinked?

Tags: symlink

I have a directory structure that looks as follows:

```
2000
  January
    01
    02
    ...
    31
  February
   ......
```

I want to create a symlink `2000` in another directory that's symlinked to the existing directory. So assuming I'm already in that other directory, I can just do:

```
ln -s /path/to/2000 2000
```

But when I cd into the `2000` that's symlinked to `/path/to/2000` and do `ls -l`, I see the same subdirectories as `/path/to/2000` (i.e., `January, February, etc...`), but it doesn't show that they're symlinked to `/path/to/2000/January`, `/path/to/2000/February`, etc... Why does it not do that?

Answer (score 1):

Because the directories you’re seeing *are* exactly the same as those in `/path/to/2000`, they’re not symlinks. You can see this by looking at the inodes with `ls -li`.